# Does changing EF Core to Transient cause issues?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have a controller action that looks like this:

```
 // GET
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {

            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
            // show events that hte user is attending
            var activitiesattending = await _activityManager.GetActivitiesAttendingForLoggedInUser();
//            var attendingActivities = _activityManager.GetActivitiesAttendingForUser()
            var activities = await _context.PlannedActivities.Select(x => new ActivityViewModel.Shared
            {
                Name = x.Name,
                Description = x.Description,
                Location = x.Location,
                PointsForCompleting = x.Points,
                ActivityImageURI = x.ActivityImageURI,
                ID = x.ID,
                isAttending = activitiesattending.Any(y => y.ID == x.ID),
                ActivityOrganiser = x.Organiser,
                BuddiesGoing = _buddyService.GetBuddiesAttendingActivity(user.Id, x.ID)
            }).ToListAsync();

            return View(new ActivityViewModel.Index(){Activities = activities});
        }
```

If I remove the call to _buddyService.GetBuddiesAttendingActivity(user.Id, x.ID) then there is no issue.

The GetBuddiesAttendingActivity function looks like this

```
   public List<ApplicationUser> GetBuddiesAttendingActivity(string UserGUID, int ActivityID)
        {
            var buddies = GetBuddiesForUser(UserGUID).Result;
            var activityattending = _activityManager.GetPeopleAttendingActivity(ActivityID).Result;

            return buddies.Intersect(activityattending).ToList();
        }
```

And the GetPeopleAttendingActivity function looks like this

```
  public async Task<List<ApplicationUser>> GetPeopleAttendingActivity(int activityid)
        {
            var peopleattending =
                await _context.ApplicationUserActivities.Where(x => x.ActivityID == activityid)
                    .Select(x => x.ApplicationUser).ToListAsync();

            return peopleattending;

        }
```

When this code is run, with default EF Core configuration for Dependency Injection, it is Scoped.  This makes the query fail because the EF Core context isn't thread safe (that's fair enough).  Changing the EF Core service type to Transient from Scoped makes the request work correctly however.

Is changing EF Core's service type from Scoped to Transient okay, or is it a sign that my code is bad and I should feel bad?  I'm somewhat new to Core and asynchronous programming so apoligies for any massive mistakes if there are some here.

Comment: Have you tried making the `GetBuddiesAttendingActivity` async?

Comment: Channging that to async means that I have to make the function call async in the Select statement.  This means I also have to change .Select(x => ...) to .Select(async x => ...) which changes the return type from List<ApplicationUser> to List<Task<ApplicationUser>> I think.  I don't really know what to do with a list of tasks... Task.All() comes to mind but I couldn't get that to work effectively either.

Comment: The scope of your context is not the issue here.  You can get all the data you need using the `Include()` extension.  e.g. `_context.PlannedActivities.Include(x => x.BuddiesGoing)`.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I'm trying to use a dependency injected service to get those details for me (I wrote a service to get that information for me).  I think that could be messing things up - I might just make this query not use that service, use Include like you suggested, and handle the logic in the Select statement (and not via the service).

Comment: I can see what you're trying to do and it's clearly not working, hence my suggestion.  It makes no sense to get that information from another service when you're already querying the context.  You can get it all in a single query and a single context.

Comment: I think you speak the truth.  After some reflection I think I just got a bit DI happy.